# Dropdownlist selected item not getting displayed in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have implemented dropdown list in asp.net mvc using following code

In controller

int iSelectedNode=2;

```
ViewData["ddlModels"] = new SelectList(Models, "ModelCode", "ModelName", iSelectedNode);
```

In View

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ModelCode", (SelectList)ViewData["ddlModels"],"--Select--",  new {id="ddlModel" })%>
```

Still all the time i get to see text "--Select--" selected all the time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `Models` collection in the controller contains an element with `ModelCode = 2`.

This being said as you've tagged your question with `asp.net-mvc-2` checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093165/dropdownlist-selectedvalue-without-postvalue-is-not-selected/3093351#3093351) for a better way to handle drop down lists using strongly typed views and helpers.